# Hydra Performance

Tags: password-cracking

I was wondering if anyone had an idea of hardware specs which improve the performance of programs like Hydra. My initial thought is that it shouldn't make too much of a difference but I wanted to know what the consensus out there was.

Comment: Can I ask why I get a - 1 for this question? I'm new to the field and I think it's a legitimate question which I can't find anything on.

Comment: Downvotes do not always require explanation, even though it might be frustrating. The tooltip for the down arrow says "lack of research effort, unclear or unhelpful". If you want to explore this deeper, you can ask on the [Meta site](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common tool for penetration testing, so no, it's not a bad question.

I'll get to the hardware below, but for raw performance, by several orders of magnitude, selecting a really appropriate password dictionary / word-list that matches both the password policy and user-base of the accounts on the system you are running this against is critical. From a performance stand-point I'd say you'd want to prioritize things in the following manner

1. Best possible account/user list
2. Best possible password/dictionary

Now we get to the primary point of your question (hardware):

3. If possible run the tests from a RAM drive. For example if you have 16GB of RAM on a laptop/system create a very large, let's say 11GB ram-drive, and load your password/dictionaries into the RAM drive in 10GB chunks. This moves your primary I/O bottleneck from being disk-bound to running at the speed of RAM.
4. Next you'll want to avoid hypervisors if possible simply because the hypervisors access to the network is shared/context-switched and will radically reduce the number of packets per second sent by a guest VM. So running on bare-metal would be ideal and understanding the packets per second rates of each piece of network infrastructure in front of your system will also help you identify other potential bottlenecks.
5. You may also want to consider going beyond a single machine. This can change your needs quite a bit as several small vm's/instances might be cheaper or faster than running this job from a single system. There are trade-offs, but ultimately this solution can scale much higher than a single system would (something to think about).
6. Finally your outbound I/O can be a bottle-neck. If possible write only good matches to the logs and store them on the ram-drive too. If every action requires a disk-write you will be slowing yourself down a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your thorough response. I will mess around with some of these ides and see what gives me the best results.